# Load large objects on app launch

Tags: android, memory-management, global-variables, android-assets

I want to load large arrays from resources and assets when my Android app is launched, and access these objects in multiple activities that are used.

Right now I am loading the resources in my launch activity:

StartActivity.java:

```
        Object heavyObject;

        onCreate() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
            @Override
            protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Assets assets = new Assets(context);
                    File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                    heavyObject = heavySetup(assetDir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return e;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

...

    public void goToNextActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(base_activity, NextActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putObject("ho", heavyObject);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

But this copies the object multiple times and causes memory issues. How can I share an object across my activities during the lifetime of an app, and only load and store them once?

Answer (score 1):

Put the data in a `static` field. This is an intentional memory leak, so be careful:

- Don't keep pouring in more data
- If you get to a point where you no longer need it, `null` out the field to allow Android to garbage-collect that data

Also, note that this data only lives as long as your process does. If Android destroys and recreates your process, you need to be in position to lazy-load this data again from your resource/asset/whatever.

Depending on the nature of the data, you might consider code generating some Java that has the data in it, the way that `R` and `BuildConfig` get generated. Then, you're guaranteed that the data is always there when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

- Register a custom `Application` instance. Checkout [How to](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class)
- You can decide to store your "large object" directly in the Application. But it's always better to keep a singleton object around
- Call the method to load your "big resource" after all is well and done in [Application#onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate). This guarantees your resource is loaded only once and is at startup of the app
- Load the said resource asynchronously.
- Voila!